# What is the shirt collar Ray Liotta wears here called?

Tags: terminology, costume-design

I’m recreating all Goodfellas suits and wanted to know what this type of shirt was called and what the type of collar he wears is called as well?

[image]

Comment: Hi Grayden, welcome to Arts & Crafts! Initially I assumed this was the same identification question you posted on Movies.SE, which would be fine, but asking where you can find items is off-topic here. Do you want to know what it's called (which was mentioned in the duplicate on Movies), or where to find it?

Comment: Ok thank you for being so kind! I’ll edit this and try it fix it! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the length, which is a little difficult to eyeball in this open position, it can be a long-point or a spearpoint/arrow collar (the latter is more informed by the fact that Goodfellas/Scorsese makes extensive use of these*).
Because of the straight lines and seemingly standard length I assume it's a long-point collar.

The type of shirt is even harder to pinpoint, since it's mostly obscured, but [The Rake](https://therake.com/stories/style/celluloid-style-goodfellas/) calls it "*an oversized camp collar shirt*", in which 'camp collar' refers more to the way it's being worn than its appearance: it's an "*open, unstructured, lay-flat collar*",  according to [ArtOfManliness](https://www.artofmanliness.com/style/clothing/the-camp-collar-shirt/).
What's also noteworthy is that, since Ray is wearing a jacket, the sleeves are likely long, whereas "*a proper fitting camp collar sleeve should end right around your elbow, and be loose, flaring out slightly*", argues  [TheEssentialMan](https://theessentialman.com/camp-collar-shirt-fit-guide-men/).

[BamfStyle](https://bamfstyle.com/2020/09/19/goodfellas-30/amp/) calls the shirt "*a one-piece “Lido collar”*" (item #17).
Searching for that, a lot more references to the **one-piece Cuban collar shirt** come up, and they clearly resemble Ray's shirt:

[image: one-piece Cuban collar shirt on TimothyEverest.co.uk]
<sup>[source](https://timothyeverest.co.uk/one-piece-cuban-collar-shirt/)</sup>

This incorporates the collar type as well, so I think this answers your question.
I left the rest of my research in because it might provide more helpful information - if not for this one, maybe for your other Goodfellas shirt reproductions :)

---

Not directly relevant, but I think you might appreciate this: in [this blog](https://therake.com/stories/style/celluloid-style-goodfellas/) on ALittleBitOfRest, the author argues the collars seen in Goodfellas are of a different breed altogether, as they are more teardrop-shaped than regular spearpoint collars, and do also seem a lot longer than the other examples there.
The author claims that they "*'ve heard reports that it was based on something worn by Italians in the 1960s*".